# Adult websites open on visiting any website in my chrome

Tags: google-chrome, virus, malware

Since, past few days, an adult website opens on visiting any website in Google Chrome.
I have re-installed my chrome, and ever reset my chrome settings.
Is their any option to prevent this virus?
I even format my windows, and it was good for few days, now again the virus is creating

**Edit:**
The same problem is present in all my vireless devices, Laptop, Andorid Tablet (Nexus 7), Phone (Nexus 5)

Comment: Most likely cause is spyware that installed an addon into your chrome. Run a scan with malwarebytes and hitmnan pro to confirm this. Once it finds something, google its name to seek proper removal instructions.

Comment: Based on your commment saying that all your devices are affected, I suggest manually setting the DNS servers on your laptop (e.g. [to Google's DNS servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) to see if that solves it on the laptop. If it does, then you probably need to reset your router *and change its settings password*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are way too many possible causes for this.  For instance, it could be your system's Proxy settings, though if you're using Microsoft Windows then this would also likely affect MS IE.  It may be good to see if Mozilla Firefox experiences the same issue, since Firefox has its own separate proxy settings.

An add-on could cause this.  Resetting customized settings wouldn't be likely to "fix" this if the add-on is still installed.  Removing add-ons might.  Re-installing Chrome might.

If info is being inserted by an external device (e.g. from a hacked router, or incorrect DNS settings that cause your traffic to go through a MITM) then this would probably not be limited to Chrome.

Anti-Virus software may detect malware that is affecting things.

So I've now mentioned multiple different approaches to possibly fix this, because there are multiple possible causes.  I expect that I haven't listed every possibility of what is causing this, but since there are so many things that could cause such an issue, we may need more details to figure out what's wrong (if the above steps don't help to more clearly identify the problem).

Comment: This same virus is in all my vireless devices, Laptop, Andorid Tablet (Nexus 7), Phone (Nexus 5)